# Pass Spring security authentication from controller methods

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC and Security and I have a controller with 2 methods.  One creates a webpage html,  and on that will take that and make a PDF out of it.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getPDFhtml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getPDFhtml(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("myPDFTemplate");
    // do stuff
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/createPDFFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView createPDFFile(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String url = "/getPDFHtml";
    String viewHtml = HttpUtil.getHttpRequest(url);
    // take viewHtml and turn it into a PDF with iText
    // other stuff...
}
```

The only way I could get this to work was to punch a hole in spring security like this (security-app-context.xml)

```
   <intercept-url pattern="/getPDFhtml/**"  access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

because tenically, my HttpUtil call is a new sesion.  (It is just a wrapper for Apache HttpClitent.jar stuff)

Now I need to not do this.  I need access to the AuthenticationTolken in getPDFhtml() and it's not there because it's authenticated ananymousy, and my manager found out about my little sceuity hack and it has to go away now. :(

so I need a way to either:

1. be able to call getPDFhtml() from createPDFFile() and have the ModelAndView render itself into an html string. (I was told 6 months ago that this is not possable, but who knows)
2. be able to call getPDFhtml() from createPDFFile() and somehow pass the jsession id or the authentication token or whatever so I can get through the Spring securuity properly.

any ideas?

Comment: A better solution is usually to inject the template engine you're using and call its rendering method directly instead of initiating a round-trip "external" call to your internal services.

Comment: Im all good with that, but HOW do I do this in Spring MVC? I assume I am using freemarker, but how do I get to the engine from a controller.

Comment: Just @Autowire it into your controller class.

Comment: @chrylis -- ooh I like that.  Which class exactly should I use? FreeMarkerView? FreeMarkerConfig?  any tips?

Comment: Check that,  I am using InternalResourceViewResolver

Comment: Whatever the template engine you're using is. It's the one that has a `render` or equivalent method.

Answer (score 0):

I went with FreeMarker.

in my main-servlet.xml I create my freemarker config:

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath"><value>/WEB-INF/freemarker/</value></property>
</bean>
```

@Autowired it into my controller and easy:

```
    Template template = freemarkerConfig.getConfiguration().getTemplate("helloWorld.ftl");
    template.process(data, out);
    String viewHtml = out.toString();
```

and off to iText it goes!  Thanks for all the help.